# Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created user table in firestore database which has attributes like (name, email, password, phone, and role).

I want to get the field role in the database to make decision to direct users and admins to different dashboard in flutter

This is my code.
[This the image of the database at firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zy05.png)

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:role_base_app/Views/admin_dashboard.dart';
import 'package:role_base_app/Views/user_dashboard.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Home"),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("Users")
                    .doc(snapshot.data!.uid)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                    final user = snapshot.data!;
                    // devtools.log(user.toString());
                    if (user['role'] == 'user') {
                      return const UserDashboard();
                    } else {
                      return const AdminDashboard();
                    }
                  }
                  return const Text("Done");
                },
              );
            }
            return const Text("well Done");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your database?

Comment: I have added the image of the database, you can check it

Answer (score 0):

[`DocumentSnapshot.data()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) is a method, so you need to invoke it by using `()`:

```
final user = snapshot.data!();
```

Comment: This is the error I'm getting The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.